# JEE/JPA - How to use DAO/CRUD-Baseclass and Entities from other Projects (Eclipse)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Multiple questions ahead.
This code works fine.

I'm working in Eclipse.
As you see from the whole setup, I'm using JTA.

**Project layout**

```
Local Project
 - servlets
    - _Index (using User)
    - _Index2 (using Person)
 - cruds
    - UserCRUD
    - PersonCRUD
 - entities
    - User

Remote/Other/Library Project
 - entities
    - Person
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
        <class>tests.jee.simple.entities.User</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script-then-metadata" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class _Index extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2039252988955365999L;

    @EJB private UserCRUD mUserCRUD;

    @Override protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResp) throws IOException {
        final User u = new User();
        u.setName("User #" + ((int) (Math.random() * 1000)));
        mUserCRUD.persist(u);

        pResp.getWriter().write("<pre>");
        final List<User> all = mUserCRUD.getAll();
        for (final User user : all) {
            pResp.getWriter().write("\t" + user + "\r\n");
        }
        pResp.getWriter().write("</pre>");
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private long    id;
    private String                      name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(final String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

CRUD/DAO/EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class UserCRUD {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager mEM;

    public void persist(final User pUser) {
        mEM.persist(pUser);
    }
    public List<User> getAll() {
        final TypedQuery<User> query = mEM.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + User.class.getSimpleName() + " i", User.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use Entities from other Eclipse projects.

Class Person in other Project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company_Person")
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private long mId;
    private String  mName;
    public Person() {}

    public void setName(final String pName) {
        mName = pName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

And CRUD in local project, right next to UserCRUD:

```
@Stateless
public class PersonCRUD {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager mEM;

    public void persist(final Person pUser) {
        mEM.persist(pUser);
    }
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        final TypedQuery<Person> query = mEM.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + Person.class.getSimpleName() + " i", Person.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Servlet #2 in local project

```
@WebServlet("/2")
public class _Index2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2039252988955365999L;

    @EJB private PersonCRUD mPersonCRUD;

    @Override protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResp) throws IOException {
        final Person u = new Person();
        u.setName("User #" + ((int) (Math.random() * 1000)));
        mPersonCRUD.persist(u);

        pResp.getWriter().write("<pre>");
        final List<Person> all = mPersonCRUD.getAll();
        for (final Person user : all) {
            pResp.getWriter().write("\t" + user + "\r\n");
        }
        pResp.getWriter().write("</pre>");
    }
}
```

But as soon as I start referencing classes from other projects (including then in the build path), JPA goes weird:

First, it tells me on deployment, that JNDI lookup failed for the additional CRUD:

> 2018-03-23T17:43:41.835+0100|Severe: Exception while deploying the app [Test_JEE_Simple] : JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [java:module/env/tests.jee.simple.servlets._Index2/mPersonCRUD], Lookup: [tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD#tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD], Type: [Session]
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD#tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD#tests.jee.simple.crud.PersonCRUD not found]

JPA does not automatically find classes from other projects, throws me ClassNotFoundExceptions.

So I add the related project to `Project->Properties->Deployment Assembly`.
Accessing the users (`/Test_JEE_Simple/ => _Index.class`) works fine.
Accessing the users (`/Test_JEE_Simple/2 => _Index2.class`) does not work, throws

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: User #706 (null/null) is not a known Entity type.

When I try adding Person.class to the persistence.xml entries, still same problem.

So here my questions:

1. Is it possible by only using JTA, or do I have to go RESOURCE_LOCAL at some point?
2. Is there a way to also have the PersonCRUD in the other project?
3. Usually I use a crud base class, and if need be, the specific classes - like UserCRUD and PersonCRUD - extend it. Works just fine. Don't wanna write loads of boilerplate code, but with that approach still can handle specific requests. So: Would it even be possible to have that generic CRUD-Class in another project?
4. Is there any way (annotations etc) to use the JTA's EntityManager Transaction? I saw a trick somewhere, but didn't test and save it, so it's lost to me...

**UPDATE:**
For some magic reason (and there seems to be a lot of magic) I can now use the Entities from other classes... Happened sometime after I added the other Project in local projects Deployment Assembly, undeployed, cleaned, closed, reopened and deployed the local project...

So the questions now remaining are 2-4, desired layout:

```
Local Project (referencing lib #1 and lib #2)
 - servlets
    - _Index (using User)
    - _Index2 (using Person)
 - cruds
    - UserCRUD: CrudBase<User>
 - entities
    - User

Remote/Other/Library Project #1 (referencing lib #2)
 - entities
    - Person
 - cruds
    - PersonCRUD: CrudBase<Person>

Remote/Other/Library Project #2 (super-library)
 - cruds
    - CrudBase<T>
```

Comment: Just as a note--you're doing lots of things by hand that Spring will do for you automatically out of the box.

Comment: Sounds awesome, but could you please be more specific about what Spring does automatically?
I know Spring to also implement JPA and lots of other features, but what exaclty would make my code parts redundant?

Comment: Spring Data JPA for handling your CRUD interfaces for you automatically, Spring Web MVC for doing all your servlet interfacing (including things like automatic parameter parsing and object retrieval, security, and HTML templating), and Boot for setting up your environment. https://start.spring.io

Comment: My Problem is: I have to use standard Glassfish/Payara. Besides EclipseLink, for such a small task, I think it's not really convenient to download another 100 MB of spring, just to get that one task done...
And in the end, I would use CrudBase<T>, which would more or less equal to using CrudRepository<T,U>